# What's the best way to have a struct that contains a reference to another struct of the same type?

Tags: rust

I have a root `Node`, and I store other `Node`s as children:

```
struct Node {
    header: Header,
    children: Vec<Node>,
    metadata: Vec<usize>,
    parent: &Node,
}
```

I want to have a way to go upwards to parent `Node`s, so I wanted to have a parent that is a reference to another `Node`. Asking around, this seems to be like a bad idea. I know I have to use lifetime declarations if I want to achieve this, but I'm not sure if the reference idea is the correct approach.

Making them `'static` would be OK in this current small program, which is a way to solve Day 8b of Advent of Code 2018.

I received this piece of information:

> just remember that you can't have 2 mutable references to the same
>   object at the same time. Those kinds of structures are easy to get
>   wrong when designed with a bunch of back pointers. Consider a memory
>   arena instead, where your relations are defined in terms of indices
>   inside that arena

I have no idea what a memory arena is or how I would implement, nor if it's actually the best way to achieve this.

Comment: I suggest reading this section from the rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html#enabling-recursive-types-with-boxes

Comment: An arena is a data structure to contain many objects of the same type, you can then refer to them by index instead of using referenes. Take a look at the [slab crate](https://crates.io/crates/slab).